# Ruby PayPal SDK, getting token info from Authorize code throws 400 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

I have created PayPal business account and I have created applicaiton in `sandbox` mode.

By using `PayPal-Ruby-SDK` I have added my `client_id`, `client_secret`, `username`, `password` and `signature` to my `paypal.yml` file.

I also, use `PayPal-Android-SDK`, which has `client_id` of this app and when my Phone application logins via PayPal, it creates that kind of response:

```
"response": { 
    "code":"mock_code_EJhi9jOPswug9TDOv93qg4Y28xIlqPDpAoqd7biDLpeGCPvORHjP1Fh4CbFPgKMGCHejdDwe9w1uDWnjPCp1lkaFBjVmjvjpFtnr6z1YeBbmfZYqa9faQT_71dmgZhMIFVkbi4yO7hk0LBHXt_wtdsw"
  },
"client": {
    "platform": "Android",
    "paypal_sdk_version": "2.14.4",
    "product_name": "PayPal-Android-SDK",
    "environment": "mock"
  },
 "response_type": "authorization_code"
}
```

Now I want to generate `refresh token` from this `code` field. I take this `code` and enter it in my ruby console:

```
tokeninfo = Tokeninfo.create('mock_code_EJhi9jOPswug9TDOv93qg4Y28xIlqPDpAoqd7biDLpeGCPvORHjP1Fh4CbFPgKMGCHejdDwe9w1uDWnjPCp1lkaFBjVmjvjpFtnr6z1YeBbmfZYqa9faQT_71dmgZhMIFVkbi4yO7hk0LBHXt_wtdsw')
```

However, this throws me that kind of error:

```
PayPal::SDK::Core::Exceptions::BadRequest: Failed.  Response code = 400.  Response message = Bad Request.  Response debug ID = 93403fd3eb431, 1998e13f9d984.
from D:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/paypal-sdk-rest-1.4.8/lib/paypal-sdk/core/util/http_helper.rb:135:in `handle_response'
from D:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/paypal-sdk-rest-1.4.8/lib/paypal-sdk/core/util/http_helper.rb:78:in `http_call'
from D:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/paypal-sdk-rest-1.4.8/lib/paypal-sdk/core/api/base.rb:86:in `api_call'
from D:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/paypal-sdk-rest-1.4.8/lib/paypal-sdk/core/api/base.rb:98:in `post'
from D:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/paypal-sdk-rest-1.4.8/lib/paypal-sdk/core/openid_connect.rb:71:in `create_from_authorization_code'
from (irb):3
from D:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
from D:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from D:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
from D:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from D:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
```

I have checked **Login with PayPal** option in my dashboard. Why this is happening?

Also, I have noticed that this `mock_code_` is same, whenever I login from different account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post answer to my own question. This could help to other people in future.

The main reason of failing `Tokeninfo.create` method is that authorization code, which is received from Android application is in **mock mode**.

Every authorization code which has **mock_code_** prefix will not work with sandbox(and live). This is just for testing in device.

In Android SDK you must set `ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX` or `ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION` instead of `ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK`.